# Java Bean:How to fetch the values from List<bean> from another bean

Tags: java, javabeans

I have one bean in that i put the another beanlist ,and i want to access that inner bean.

My First Bean is:

```
public class FirstDTO {
private String Fname= "";
private String name= "";
private List<studentTransactionDTO> studentTransactionDTOList = new ArrayList<studentTransactionDTO>();
getter and setters....
```

and my second Bean is:

```
public class studentTransactionDTO {

private String age= "";
private String lName = "";
private String marks = "";
getter and setters....
```

Please give me some suggestion to retrieve value from inner bean.

Regards.

Comment: Provide accessor methods in the FirstBean; no other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way

```
    FirstDTO  firstDTO=new FirstDTO();// FirstDTO instance
    List<studentTransactionDTO>  list=firstDTO.getStudentTransactionDTOList();
    // list of studentTrasactionDTO in firstDTO

    String age=list.get(0).getAge(); // name of first element in list
```

You can iterate entire list as follows

```
    for(studentTransactionDTO i:list){
       i.getName()// you can access i's properties.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FirstDTO  firstDTO = new FirstDTO();
List<studentTransactionDTO> list = firstDTO.getStudentTransactionDTOList();
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    String age = list.get(i).getAge();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in the first bean you need to add a getter method to the list bean like :

```
public studentTransactionDTO getStudentTransactionDTO(int index) {
    return studentTransactionDTOList.get(index);
}
```

then you can access it by :

```
studentTransactionDTO std = firstBeanObject.getStudentTransactionDTO(0);
std.getAge();
```